# Adding an image background similar to atom io in a HTML page

Tags: html, css

I want to know how the [atom.io](https://atom.io/) website has got its background. When I checked the source there aren't no link of an image. When I R-Click on the image I can't save it too.

May i know how to get a similar feature on the website I am developing ?

Comment: They have added the background image on `.call-to-action` class and it is easily visible using firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use a `<div>` with a CSS background image.

If you want to do something similar write your `div` like:

```
<div class="mybackground"></div>
```

and write this CSS in your stylesheet:

```
.mybackground {
    height: 590px;
    background-image: url("yourimage.png");
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-size: auto, auto 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To continue on from @Simrandeep Singh, you would use something like this within css:

```
.hero {
  background-image:url('/path/to/image');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Please note atom.io have used an svg image, probably created using a program such as Adobe Illustrator. This uses vector shapes to create the image which can be animated on websites (this can be seen in the images when you scroll down on the page).

I hope this helps.